# How to use timenow to fetch objects with two dates even if one of the dates is in the past in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I have a `trips` model that has `in_flights` and `out_flights` associated to a `Client`.

I wanted to show which `Clients` have trips after *now* so I did the following:

```
ls= Clients.objects.get(nif=nif
ClientsDash = (Clients.objects.filter(trip__in_flight__date__gt=timezone.now()).filter(trip__out_flight__date__gt=timezone.now()).distinct())
```

The problem is, if one Client has one of the flights in the past, or only one of the flights, it won't display the `trip`.

**EDIT**

This is the `Trip` model

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    trip_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, verbose_name="Ref. Viagem")
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, verbose_name='Destino')
    client = models.ForeignKey(Clients, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Cliente")
    out_flight = models.ForeignKey(Flight, related_name="outbound_flight" , null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Voo Ida")
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotels, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Hotel")
    in_flight = models.ForeignKey (Flight, related_name="inbound_flight", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Voo Regresso")
```

And the `Flight` model

```
class Flight(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, verbose_name="Data")
    flight_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Ref. Voo")
    company = models.ForeignKey(AirCompany, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Companhia")
    airport = models.ForeignKey(Airport, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Aeroporto")
```

Comment: Is it possible to share relevant parts of your models? Is `in_flights` a `ForeignKey`? Or a `ManyToManyFieldd`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You here filter the collection twice, so that means that you only will retrieve `Client`s that have a `trip__in_flight` *and* a `trip__out_flight` that is in the future.

You can however use a logical or `|`, to specify that one flight is sufficient:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Clients.objects.filter(
    Q(trip__in_flight__date__gt=timezone.now()) |
    Q(trip__out_flight__date__gt=timezone.now())
).distinct()
```

Comment: that worked perfectly. Thanks, and it was a great example to understand how is Q used!